# 500 Internal Error when calling function from withing namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a file with several functions which are within the namespace `LOM`.  One is called `get_cart_total()`.  When I'm outside that file calling the function all is well...

`$total_value = LOM\get_cart_total()[0];` works fine.

But when I'm in that file, calling it I get a 500 Internal Error...

`$total_value = get_cart_total()[0];` fails (I'm in the file namespaced `LOM`).

Even doing a `var_dump()` on `get_cart_total()` causes the 500 error from **within** the namespaced file, but var dumping it **outside** the namespaced file is fine.

Note: PHP version is 7.0.25.

Any ideas?

Per comment request, the code for `get_cart_total()` is...

```
    //For updating the subtotal and/or total in the shopping cart
function get_cart_total($additional_parameters_array = array()){
    $db = \DB::getInstance(); //For including the database object/class.
    global $user; //Get the $user object 

    //Get list of product ids for this order
    $products_array = get_product_id_array_for_order_in_process();

    //Calculate the $sub_total.
    $sub_total = 0;
    foreach($products_array as $product_id){
        if($product_id == 0){ //It's tutoring, so do this differently than other things.
            //Get the number of hours of tutoring that are currently in the cart.
            $hrs = tutoring_hrs_in_cart();

            $sub_total = $sub_total + tutoring_total_price($hrs);
        } else { //It's not tutoring, so just get the price and add it in.
            $sub_total = $sub_total + get_product_price($product_id);   
        }           
    }

    //Apply payment method fee_discount if applicable
        //Get the fee_discount for an order that's in process based on the products and subtotal.
        $fee_discount = get_payment_method_fee_discount_for_order_in_process();

        $total = $fee_discount + $sub_total;


    //Apply store credit
        //See if we're applying store credit.
        $apply_store_credit = applying_store_credit_for_order_in_process();

        //We are applying store credit, so reduce $total by that amount.
        if($apply_store_credit == 1){
            $store_credit_amount = get_store_credit($user->data()->id);
            $total = $total - $store_credit_amount;
        }

        //We can't have a negative order total, so if it's negative, just make the $total = 0.
        if($total < 0){
            $total = 0;
        }           

    $total_array[] = $total;
    $total_array[] = $sub_total;

    return $total_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're  using a class

You can invoke a method in another method within same class using "self"

```
$total_value = self::get_cart_total()[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not in a class, actually.  Trying your solution gave `Fatal error: Cannot use "self" when no class scope is active in`.

Comment: Check you php error log file for exact line of error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting myself into a loop where I called one function `get_payment_method_fee_discount_for_order_in_process()` from within another `get_cart_total()`, then the original function in that one, etc.

Please keep driving... nothing to see here.